# SmartAdmin HTML Version Nav Bug - Doubling up Anchor on Multiple Level Navigation

Tags: javascript, anchor, nav, smartadmin

I think it is an issue with HTML I am generating from asp.net and via the C# code behind. Essentially, I am generating the SmartAdmin nav using a ListView which has a code behind function bound to it's OnItemDataBound function.

```
<asp:ListView OnItemDataBound="lvwMenu_ItemDataBound" ID="lvwMenu" runat="server" >
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <nav>
                        <!-- 
                        NOTE: Notice the gaps after each icon usage <i></i>..
                        Please note that these links work a bit different than
                        traditional href="" links. See documentation for details.
                        -->
                        <ul>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li class="<%# If(Container.DataItemIndex.Equals(0), "active", "")%>">
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="pnlAnchorAll" runat="server">
                            <a id="lkbtnData" runat="server" title='<%# Bind("Description")%>'>
                                <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Label") %>"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%></span>
                                <%--     Repeater is here generating second level of pages    --%> 
                            </a>
                        </asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

Here is the DataBound Event Code Behind function:

```
Protected Sub lvwMenu_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs)
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
        Dim rowView As DataRowView
        rowView = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)

        Dim lkbtnData As HtmlAnchor, pnlAnchorAll As PlaceHolder, rptSubMenu As Repeater

        If rowView("Description").ToString().Equals("Second Level", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
            rptSubMenu = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("rptSubMenu"), Repeater)
            oBSAOM = New MD.bsAOM(_oSession:=Session)
            oBSAOM.bGetSecondLevel("Pages", rptSubMenu)
            lkbtnData.HRef = "javascript:void(0)"
        Else
            lkbtnData.HRef = rowView("Value").ToString()
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

I am using a repeater to generate a second level of pages

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSubMenu" runat="server">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ul class="">
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <li>
                                            <a id="lkbtnSubData" runat="server" title='<%# Bind("Description")%>' href='<%# Bind("Value")%>'>
                                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-folder-open"></i> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        </ul>
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
```

And the generated source when outputted to the browser is:

```
            <nav>
                        <!-- 
                        NOTE: Notice the gaps after each icon usage <i></i>..
                        Please note that these links work a bit different than
                        traditional href="" links. See documentation for details.
                        -->
                <ul>

                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="Home.aspx" id="ctl00_lvwMenu_ctrl0_lkbtnData" title="Home">
                                <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Home</span>

                            </a>


                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="ctl00_lvwMenu_ctrl5_lkbtnData" title="Second Level">
                                <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-dollar"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Second Level</span>
                                <!-- BEGIN Second Level Example here -->
                                    <ul>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="../SecondLevel/Page.aspx" id="ctl00_lvwMenu_ctrl5_rptSubMenu_ctl01_lkbtnData" title="2nd Level Page">
                                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-folder-open"></i> 2nd Level Page
                                            </a>
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                <!-- END Second Level Example here -->    
                         </a>


                    </li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Which looks correct. But what is happening immediately on page load is the source is modified (I presume by SmartAdmin's JS) to:

```
<li>
                <a title="Second Level" id="ctl00_lvwMenu_ctrl5_lkbtnData" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-dollar"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Second Level</span>
                    <b class="collapse-sign"><em class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></em></b>
                </a>
                <!-- BEGIN Second Level Example here -->
                <ul style="display: none;">
                    <a title="Second Level" id="ctl00_lvwMenu_ctrl5_lkbtnData" href="javascript:void(0)">  <!-- Anchor Tag is incorrectly generated here -->
                    </a>
                    <li>
                        <a title="Second Level" id="ctl00_lvwMenu_ctrl5_lkbtnData" href="javascript:void(0)"> <!-- Anchor Tag is incorrectly generated here -->
                        <a title="Page" id="ctl00_lvwMenu_ctrl5_rptSubMenu_ctl01_lkbtnSubData" href="../SecondLevel/Page.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-folder-open"></i> Page
                        </a>
                     </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- END Second Level Example here -->                 
        </li>
```

Has anyone run into a similar problem before by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later figured out it was an error on my part with how I was generating the HTML using the ASP:Repeater. The Smart admin JS didn't expect to have it produced in that format on page load and thus, it broke.